# solr DoS protection

Tags: solr, denial-of-service

Our web app has recently become the target of some DDoSers. We use solr and they managed to generate 100% load by searching for "**" every few seconds. Can someone tell me why that query takes tens of seconds to run, whereas everything else takes just milliseconds? Also, the code appends the user ID to the search so the query was "userid: 10 AND **", which shouldn't really slow down because that user only has 10 documents or so.

Does anyone know what's going on, and how we can best protect ourselves from it?

Thank you.

Comment: @Stavros Korokithakis - how is your page translate into solr query? is it just simply depend on GET ?

Comment: It does perform some transformations, but mainly it's the GET string, yes. It's worked very well so far, but I don't know why \*\* takes this long.

Comment: what's your default search field? is it a big text field?

Comment: @Stavros Korokithakis - any example of bogus URL?

Comment: It's just a search on our site, which takes minutes to complete. It doesn't have anything to do with our code, solr just takes minutes to return "userid:10 AND **".

Comment: what's your default search field?

Comment: @Stavros Korokithakis: `userid:10 AND **` does not sound correct, why dun u trim it to use `+(userid:10)` as suggested by @Maurico Scheffer

Answer (score 1):

`**` gets interpreted by Solr as a query with leading and ending wildcard and since these is no defined field it lands on your default search field, which (as your said in the comments) is a big text field. So it ends up searching for everything which is probably why it takes so long.

Solution: filter out `**` in your application before passing the query to Solr.  You could even filter all `*` if you don't want to allow your users to issue any wildcard queries.

Comment: It does, but there's no reason why it should take minutes to search a ten-item set... I filtered out all the special Lucene characters as a stopgap (?, *, {, ~), but the dismax parser looks better for user-facing setups. That, however, has its own quirks, which I hope to overcome.

Comment: @Stavros: yes, some sanitizing might be still needed even with dismax. Try running the problematic query with debugQuery=on to see why it takes so long.